# I can't get INNER JOIN to work "ORA 00918"

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have a query that returns all the correct rows I need which looks like this:

```
SELECT sequence_no,
MAX(time)
FROM ensapp.shop_order_analysis
WHERE analyzer='SORVI01'
AND part_no in ('PTS228AL','PSS1285')
AND sequence_no in ('6','9','*')
AND SYSDATE-15<time group by sequence_no
```

But I want it to return one more column and when I try to do an INNER JOIN it says "ORA-00918: Column ambiguously defined". I tried to google this but couldn't make any sense out of it. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT part_no, sequence_no, time
FROM ensapp.shop_order_analysis a
INNER JOIN(
SELECT sequence_no,
MAX(time)
FROM ensapp.shop_order_analysis
WHERE analyzer='SORVI01'
AND part_no in ('PTS228AL','PSS1285')
AND sequence_no in ('6','9','*')
AND SYSDATE-15<time group by sequence_no) c 
ON a.sequence_no=c.sequence_no
```

I am a beginner in SQL. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, always qualify your column names.  Then you will never have this problem:

```
SELECT a.part_no, a.sequence_no, a.time
FROM ensapp.shop_order_analysis a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT sequence_no, MAX(time) as maxt
      FROM ensapp.shop_order_analysis
      WHERE analyzer = 'SORVI01' AND
            part_no in ('PTS228AL','PSS1285') AND
            sequence_no in ('6', '9', '*') AND
            SYSDATE-15 < time
      GROUP BY sequence_no
     ) aa
     ON a.sequence_no = aa.sequence_no;
```

I am guessing, though, that you really want:

```
SELECT a.*, MAX(a.time) OVER () as maxt
FROM ensapp.shop_order_analysis s
WHERE analyzer = 'SORVI01' AND
      part_no in ('PTS228AL','PSS1285') AND
      sequence_no in ('6', '9', '*') AND
      SYSDATE - 15 < time;
```

Comment: I think that your 'guess' is what makes this answer great.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the first one returns all the rows that have the sequence_no '6','9' or '*', I only want the ones with the part_no 'PTS228AL' and 'PSS1285'. And your "guess" says invalid identifier. I think I am able to do this now though. Thank you for your help